# Autogenerated IntermediateOutputPath in the .csproj file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

After updating the code from Git I have an error in the `csproj`, because the `file` path doesn't exist. Here is the code which initiates the error:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'ZAL_Release|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>..\Release\bin\soft\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;ZAL</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\Users\HARRY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vs543E.tmp\x64\ZAL_Release\</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This `filepath` exists on Harry's computer, but not on mine. The guy with this name has no idea how he created this, so I assume Visual Studio created it. That's why I have three questions:

**1.** What's the goal of `IntermediateOutputPath` tag in the `csproj`? (I already checked MSDN documentation, but still not clear)

**2.** How did Harry generat the code (because he doesn't know)?

**3.** Is it possible to use a generic variable to get a file path that everybody could use? In the case, is this `IntermediateOutputPath` mandatory for the program to run?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous : I don't understand why you want me to delete the csproj file and then open the project. If I do this it will not open the project and i can even lose some datas like the project references.

Comment: By all means, you should definitely **NOT** remove this file from git. The .csproj file is the central project file for every visual studio project and people will not be able to work on your project without it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. An `OutputPath` in your project file

   > Specifies the path to the output directory, relative to the project directory, for example, "bin\Debug".

   The `BaseOutputPath`

   > Specifies the base path for the output file. If it is set, MSBuild will use OutputPath = $(BaseOutputPath)\$(Configuration). Example syntax: c:\xyz\bin\

   The `BaseIntermediateOutputPath`

   > The top-level folder where all configuration-specific intermediate output folders are created. The default value is obj. The following code is an example: c:\xyz\obj\

   The `IntermediateOutputPath`

   > The full intermediate output path as derived from BaseIntermediateOutputPath, if no path is specified. For example, \obj\debug. If this property is overridden, then setting BaseIntermediateOutputPath has no effect.

   You can read this up [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx). In general these Paths should be relative and in no way lead to any home folders or other user-specific paths.
2. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26638135/7598462) for an explanation of how the `IntermediateOutputPath` may have been inserted in your csproj file.

   EDIT: Actually, this is a vague explanation, but I could not find any other info about this. Keep an eye on changes on your csproj file to pin down the reason for the change.
3. You can set `IntermediateOutputPath` to a relative path. You can, however, also just delete the whole tag and go with the default. In our Visual Studio 2015 project files, we only set the base `OutputPath`, and everything is working fine. I think the default place for your intermediate objects is `/obj`.

Comment: Ok I deleted the line IntermediateOutputPath and it works fine. Everybody is happy. Thank @kowsky

Comment: Not fine. Every time I publish from command line, Visual Studio keeps interjecting this user-specific, absolute path, and there's no way to stop it. Major bug. Lastest version of Visual Studio 2019 as of writing this comment.

Comment: @Triynko Did you ever make any progress in resolving VS2019's stubborness? I have the same issue you've described.